# Tensorflow RNN shape mismatch- logits_size=[5,2] labels_size=[50,2] - Batch size is 10

Tags: tensorflow, lstm

I'm working on a simple LSTM implementation in Tensorflow and having some trouble with the dimensions. So, my

```
batch size = 10
time_steps = 5
num_classes = 2 
input_size = 4
```

The placeholders are

`x = tf.placeholder('float',[None,time_steps,input_size])`

`y = tf.placeholder('float',[None,None,num_classes])`

I run it by feeding data from a csv file

`_, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: _x, y: _y})`
where I've set `_x.shape = (10, 5, 4)` and `_y.shape = (10, 5, 2)`
in accordance with the `(batch,time_steps, input_size)` requirement of TF.

I've gone through a few implementations(mostly on the MNIST dataset) on the internet and blog posts and I think I've understood how it works. TF expects the logits and labels arguments to be 2-D tensors with batch_size rows, and num_classes columns. Now, I have a classification label for each entry. I've converted them into the one-hot format. If I provide a total of 50 entries from the data, I should be providing 50 labels too, right?

Changing the y placeholder to `[None,num_classes]` and consequently some other stuff also gave an error.

But if I change my `batch_size` to 1, I can get the code to run, until the line

`correct = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))`
where I get an error 
`ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 5 and 2 for 'Equal' (op: 'Equal') with input shapes: [5], [?,2].` 
because prediction shape is `(5, 2)` whereas y is `(?, ?, 2)`

Is there a fundamental mistake in my understanding of how it should work?

The full code can be viewed at [Simple RNN Gist](https://gist.github.com/avi-jain/9e40c41a991041a45a2e24bd77de388c)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 30 of your code does something weird with the output of your RNN. The RNN output its typically a 3D tensor (batch_size, time_steps, cell_output_dim) which becomes a 2D with the slicing operation (outputs[-1]). Obviously, the loss function does not expect this kind of tensor so you got an error. If you want to apply a Feedforward neural network on a multidimensional tensor I suggest you to use the [tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/fully_connected) function that will automatically create weights for your network and will apply the correct operation on the input tensor.

There is another error in your code. You are trying to apply the softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits on a 3D tensor. Unfortunately you cannot do that so you need to do the following:

1. Reshape your tensor to dimensions (batch_size * time_steps, num_classes);
2. Apply the loss function for each one of the batch_size * time_steps examples by using the softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits (which can be correctly applied now);
3. Average the loss values (this is only a possibility, you can aggregate the loss values as you wish).

I cannot provide a complete solution here because I have not your data so I am not able to exactly execute your code. However, I will report the following simplified snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn 

num_classes = 2
batch_size  = 10
time_steps = 5

#input has 4 features
input_size = 4
num_hidden = 6

x = tf.placeholder('float',[None,time_steps,input_size])
y = tf.placeholder('float',[None,None,num_classes])

def neural_net_model(data):
    lstmCell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_hidden)

    outputs, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstmCell,x, dtype=tf.float32)
    print(outputs)

    output = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
        outputs,
        num_classes,
        weights_initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer()
    )
    return output

def train_neural_net(x):
    num_epochs = 2
    num_examples = 1000 #np_df.shape[0] - reduced to 1000 for debugging 
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        predictions = neural_net_model(x)
        reshaped_predictions = tf.reshape(predictions, (-1, num_classes))
        reshaped_targets = tf.reshape(y, (-1, num_classes))
        cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=reshaped_predictions,labels=reshaped_targets))
```

Comment: Thanks :) This seems to work. So from what I gather, if I provide my labels, _y in this example, in the form of a 3D matrix (10x5x2 in my case) I need to reduce it to a 2D tensor (50x2 here) before applying the cost function on it? And the same needed to be done to the predictions, which are returned in the form of a 3D matrix

Comment: Exactly, it is correct. In fact this is what I do in the simplified snippet that I have reported. If you are satisfied by the answer feel free to mark it as solved :)

Comment: Minor doubt so I might as well ask it here itself. How do I go about calculating the accuracy on some test data(or in training itself) in this case where I fetch rows from a csv file, format and feed it to the model.  The simple `sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})` wouldn't suffice. I updated the gist to give some clarity
Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to define the related accuracy op (have a look to the TF metrics before implementing it from scratch) and you need to execute it exactly as all the other op that you define in TF. Obviously, you need to specify the input data on which you want to compute the metric in the `session.run()` invocation.